# R obj must be a foreach object error after update

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I've been using R's `doParallel` and `foreach` package. I updated R and these packages recently (not sure if related to this issue) and noticed this error:

```
> foreach(a=1:3, b=rep(10, 3)) %do% (a + b)
Error in e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data) : 
  obj must be a foreach object
```

The example is one from the `foreach` vignette. Whats the issue?

<s>EDIT:</s>

Started up new R session, re-installed `doParallel` and issue went away.

Comment: Suggest modifying the question to indicate that it's effectively closed, then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you load `memisc` after the `doParallel` package, you'll get the warning message:

```
The following object(s) are masked from ‘package:foreach’:

    foreach
```

Executing a foreach loop will now generate the "obj must be a foreach object" error because you won't be using the correct foreach function.

You can use the `::` operator to avoid the problem:

```
foreach::foreach(a=1:3, b=rep(10, 3)) %do% (a + b)
```

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that loading the `memisc` package before `doParallel` was causing the problem.